# PagedListPager() method is not working while all configurations are okay

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a simple pagination view as follows:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<PgcbSms.Core.Entities.SmsLog>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SMSLog";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>SMSLog</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().originator)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().content)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().messageDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().receivedDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().dbinsertdate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().status)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.originator)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.content)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.messageDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.receivedDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dbinsertdate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("SMSLog", new { page}))
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

I add the two lines:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

and study about pagination code in asp.net mvc but nothing is missed in my code. So why I am getting such error? Any Idea? thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:**
Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PgcbSms.Core.Entities;
using PgcbSms.Services.SmsLogServices;
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;

namespace PgcgSms.WebSite.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        private ISmsLogService _smsLogService;
        public ReportsController(ISmsLogService smsLogService)
        {
            _smsLogService = smsLogService;
        }
        public IActionResult SMSLog(int? page)
        {
            IPagedList<SmsLog> smsLogs = _smsLogService.GetSmsLogsPaged(page);
            return View(smsLogs);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update2:**

```
 public IPagedList<SmsLog> GetSmsLogsPaged(int? page)
        {
            return _smsRepository.Table.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) (which you need to core-mvc)?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How can I confirm that?

Comment: Your not, because other wise it would be `@using X.PagedList.Mvc`

Comment: Not working. I installed PagedList.Mvc through package manager.

Comment: You need to use X.PagedList

Comment: Install X.PagedList  but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182713/discussion-between-abdus-sattar-bhuiyan-and-stephen-muecke).